# Alternative to if statements

Tags: jquery

I want to find out if there is a way to avoid having 100's - 1000's of if statements. What my application will do is based on which suburb the user enters. It will find 5 of the closest stores to the suburb.

Since all the results would be different, is there a way to list the closest 5 stores of each suburb without having an if statement for each suburb? Just for part of a state it will be 99 if statements.

EDIT:

I'll add a quick mock up of the code seeing as I haven't got it with me atm

```
var locationArray = ["suburb1", "suburb2", "suburb3", "suburb4", "suburb5", "suburb6", "suburb7", "suburb8", "suburb9", "suburb10"];

$("#suburbSearch").focusout(function() {
    if($.inArray($("#suburbSearch").val(), locationArray) != -1)
    {
        if($("#suburbSearch").val() == "suburb1")
        $("#radSec").html("");
        $("#radSec").append(enterSuburb1 + enterSuburb2 + enterSuburb3 + enterSuburb4 + enterSuburb5);
    }
    else
        alert("It's Not There");
});
```

This is what I have so far just to see if it would work. If I were to continue on this way I would need to do:

```
if($("#suburbSearch").val() == "suburb1")
        $("#radSec").html("");
        $("#radSec").append(enterSuburb1 + enterSuburb2 + enterSuburb3 + enterSuburb4 + enterSuburb5);
```

A ridiculous amount

Comment: it would be helpful if you show a sample if condition of how you're determining the closest suburb.

Comment: You can use the function instead of if statement. And its depend on your code.

Comment: I've added in a mock up of my code because I haven't got the real code on my right now

Comment: Use a loop?
"asking these type of questions makes me think if programming is really for you."

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this as static html, then you can use dictionaries for this relatively easily.

Something like this:

```
var locationLookups = {"suburb1": ["store1", "store2", "store3"],
                       "suburb2": ["store4", "store5", "store6"]};

var target = locationLookups["suburb1"]; // target contains array of store1-3
```

then you need only look up the suburb and you get all the stores.. if you want the list of suburbs, you need only use `Object.Keys(locationLookups)` to get the array of suburbs.  If you want the entire list of stores, you would need to loop through the dictionary and build a list, or you can just keep a separate list.

Using your example:

```
$("#suburbSearch").focusout(function() {
    if($.inArray($("#suburbSearch").val(), Object.Keys(locationLookups)) != -1)
    {
        $("#radSec").html(locationLookups[$("#suburbSearch").val()].join(''));
    }
    else
        alert("It's Not There");
});
```

Ideally, you would have some web service you call that returns the list of stores based on a geographical zipcode search and distance from the location or similar... but if you want to hardcode it, the dictionary is the best choice.

Comment: @John - I just added an example using your original example, this is all that's needed... (well, obviously, you probably need to flesh it out to display what you actually want).

Comment: Is there a limit to the amount of key words I can enter per array?

Comment: @John - in theory, yes... in practice not really... You're limited by the amount of memory available to the javascript engine by the browser.  In most cases, you probably won't have to worry about it.. even with hundreds or thousands of entries.  Remember, though.. the user has to download all that text.. so the more stuff you have in the page, the longer the page will take to download.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably just go with just gps and determining from that. Seems a lot easier